# Adding a percent symbol to xtabs cells in r

Tags: r, pander

I'm trying to use the R packages `survey` and `pander` for some quick table and report generation, but can't seem to format a table the way I need. I'd like to add percent symbols after the appropriate cells to the table.

Here's my code to generate the table. The cells are normalized to 100, so I just need to add the percent symbol (%) somehow to the markdown output.

```
library(pander)
library(survey)
employee_id <- c(1020:1069)
Q9_1 <- rep(as.factor(c('Unsatisfied','Neutral','Satisfied','Satisfied','Satisfied')),10)
employee <- data.frame(employee_id,Q9_1)
employee_survey <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~1, data=employee)
pandoc.table(svytable(~Q9_1,employee_survey,Ntotal=100))
```

Am I just missing a simple option here? I've searched and searched, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: So we are supposed to guess at the structure of 'employee' or provide a substitute? Why not also include the names of the packages and sample data in a cut-pastable form?

Comment: Why not place `%` in the row or column label. this mean less "noise" in the table. AFAIK there isn't an option within `pandoc.table` to process the values in this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably something along these lines, obviously replacing `tbl` with `employee_survey`  ...still untested.

```
scratch <- attr(tbl, "dimnames")
scratch$stype=paste(scratch$stype, "%")
scratch -> attr(tbl, "dimnames")
pandoc.table(tbl)
```

A somewhat similar process is possible on the cell contents. Again tested only on the example in `?svytable`:

```
 ntbl <- as.character(round(tbl, 2))
 ntbl <- paste(ntbl, "%")
 attributes(ntbl) <- attributes(tbl)
 ntbl
 #---------------    
    stype
sch.wide E        H        M       
     No  406.16 % 101.54 % 270.78 %
     Yes 4467.8 % 372.32 % 575.4 % 
 #-------------
pandoc.table(ntbl)
#----------------------------------

------------------------------------
 &nbsp;      E        H        M    
--------- -------- -------- --------
 **No**   406.16 % 101.54 % 270.78 %

 **Yes**  4467.8 % 372.32 % 575.4 % 
------------------------------------
```

Depending on how you want the significant digits displayed this is also possible:

```
 ntbl <- format(round(tbl, 2),digits=5)
 attributes(ntbl) <- attributes(tbl)
 pandoc.table(ntbl)

-------------------------------
 &nbsp;      E      H      M   
--------- ------- ------ ------
 **No**   406.16  101.54 270.78

 **Yes**  4467.80 372.32 575.40
-------------------------------
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks for the quick work, DWin. Spacing between the percent symbol (%) and the number can be controlled by the sep argument in the paste function, i.e., sep="".